# Want to verify my approach

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> If repetition of digit is not allowed, then how many five digit numbers which are divisible by $3$ can be formed
> using the digits?

My approach is that i made 3 sets of digits according to the remainder they give on dividing by $3$ -
$ A:(0,3,6,9)$ , $B:(1,4,7)$ , $C:(2,5,8)$, Now the following cases are possible:

1. Any $1$ digit from $A$ $+$ Any $2$ digit from $B$ $+$ Any $2$ digit from $C$ , Now $0$ should not come at Ten thousandths place So handling it in two subcases , when $0$ is chosen from $A$ $\big(1 \cdot {3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 2}\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big) + $ when $0$ not chosen $\big({3 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 2}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big)$
2. Any $2$ digit from $A$ $+$ Any $3$ digit from $B$ $+$ Any $0$ digit from $C$ , Now $0$ should not come at Ten thousandths place So handling it in two subcases , when $0$ is chosen from $A$ $\big(1\cdot {3 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 3} \cdot {3 \choose 0}\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big) + $ when $0$ not chosen $\big({3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 3}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big)$
3. Any $2$ digit from $A$ $+$ Any $0$ digit from $B$ $+$ Any $3$ digit from $C$ , Now $0$ should not come at Ten thousandths place So handling it in two subcases , when $0$ is chosen from $A$ $\big(1 \cdot {3 \choose 1}\cdot {3 \choose 0} \cdot {3 \choose 3}\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big) + $ when $0$ not chosen $\big({3 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 3}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big)$
4. Any $3$ digit from $A$ $+$ Any $1$ digit from $B$ $+$ Any $1$ digit from $C$ , Now $0$ should not come at Ten thousandths place So handling it in two subcases , when $0$ is chosen from $A$ $\big(1 \cdot {3 \choose 2}\cdot {3 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 1}\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big) + $ when $0$ not chosen $\big({3 \choose 3} \cdot {3 \choose 1}\cdot {3 \choose 1}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \big)$.

> Total $= 9072$

pls verify my approach and answer, other methods will also be appreciated ,Thanks.

Comment: This can be counted in Mathematica via the following command: `Count[Range[10^4,10^5],x_/;DuplicateFreeQ[IntegerDigits[x]]&&Divisible[x,3]]`. This generates numbers from 10000 to 100000, then counts how many have distinct digits and are multiples of 3. That gives a count of 9072, in agreement with your work.

Comment: Also in Python, `len([a for a in range(10000,100000) if len(set(str(a)))==5 and a%3==0])` - the unique digit requirement checked via whether the set of characters has 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The count can be simplified using probability  as under:

Without zeroes, there will be $\binom9 5 = 126$ digit strings, *and the same number* with zeroes, at$\,\binom9 4 = 126$

$\frac 1 3$ of each, i.e. $42$ will be divisible by $3$, but since zeroes can only be allowed at $4$ of the $5$ digits, the multiplication factor while combining them won't be $2$ but $1.8$

Thus answer $= 42\times1.8\times5! = 9072\,$, which confirms your answer

Comment: "1/3rd of each..."

Comment: @Light Yagami : Quite right. Have corrected typo, thanks !

Comment: That doesn't follow. You can get a correct answer by incorrect methods.

Comment: @new QOpenGLWidget : What is the fallacy ?